# Memory leak caused by thread usage for sessions and transactions?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, tomcat, memory-leaks

I'm hunting down a memory leak in a JSF application. I've read various articles that discuss potential memory leaks when using threads with transactions and sessions. Does the following code seem like it could produce a leak? This code is called thousands of times (for page requests).

```
public class HibernateHelper 
{
      private static final ThreadLocal threadSession = new ThreadLocal();
      private static final ThreadLocal threadTransaction = new ThreadLocal();  

      public static Session startSessionWithDBName(SessionFactorySingleton.DBname dbname) 
      {
            Session s = getSessionWithDBName(dbname);
            beginTransaction(dbname);
            return s;
      }   

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      private static Session getSessionWithDBName(SessionFactorySingleton.DBname dbname) 
      {         
            Session s = (Session) threadSession.get();
            if (s == null) 
            {
                s = SessionFactorySingleton.getSessionFactory(dbname).openSession();                
                threadSession.set(s);
            }
            else 
            {
                String sf = ((SessionFactoryImpl)s.getSessionFactory()).getProperties().getProperty("hibernate.session_factory_name");
                if((dbname !=null && sf !=null) && !sf.equals(dbname.toString()))
                {                   
                    closeSessionBySessionFactoryName(sf);
                    s = SessionFactorySingleton.getSessionFactory(dbname).openSession();
                    threadSession.set(s);           
                }               
            }
            return s;
      }   

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public static boolean isSessionOpen() 
      {         
            Session s = (Session) threadSession.get();
            if (s != null)              
                return s.isOpen();
            return false;           
      }   

      public static boolean wasTransactionCommited() 
      {         
            Transaction t = (Transaction) threadTransaction.get();          
            if (t != null) 
                return t.wasCommitted();
            return false;           
      } 

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public static void closeSessionBySessionFactoryName(String sessionfactoryname) {          
            Session s = (Session) threadSession.get();          
            if (s != null && s.isOpen()) 
            {   
                String sfname = ((SessionFactoryImpl)s.getSessionFactory()).getProperties().getProperty("hibernate.session_factory_name");
                if(sfname.equals(sessionfactoryname))
                {               
                    try 
                    {
                        commitTransaction(sfname);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                   
                    s.close();
                    threadSession.set(null);    
                }
            }           
        }

        /**
         * Start a new database transaction.
         */
        private static void beginTransaction(SessionFactorySingleton.DBname dbname) {           
            Session s = (Session) threadSession.get();                              
            if(s!=null)
            {
                log.info("Starting new transaction for this thread.");
                Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
                threadTransaction.set(tx);
            }                                           
        }

        /**
         * Commit the database transaction.
         */
        public static void commitTransaction(String sessionfactoryname) throws Exception {          
            Transaction tx = (Transaction) threadTransaction.get();
            try {
                if (tx != null && !tx.wasCommitted() && !tx.wasRolledBack()) {
                    tx.commit();                    
                    log.info("Committed transaction for thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());                    
                }
                threadTransaction.set(null);
            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                log.error("Exception when committing transaction: ", e);
                rollbackTransactionKeepingSessionOpen();
                throw e;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Rollback the database transaction.
         */
        public static void rollbackTransactionKeepingSessionOpen() {    
            Transaction tx = (Transaction) threadTransaction.get();
            threadTransaction.set(null);
            if (tx != null && !tx.wasCommitted() && !tx.wasRolledBack()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Use a profiler and find the stack places where the memory leak is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.
Each threadLocal instance is bound to a lifespan of a thread that uses it.
Tomcat's thread pool can easily have hundreds of threads; each thread is reused and never destroyed.
Some of them will be stuck in an I/O operation, querying DB or whatnot, at the same time holding a reference to an open Hibernate session (which in turn may contain a lot of attached entities).
So during some periods the application may have many big object graphs that cannot be reclaimed by GC.
I think you should manage Hibernate sessions and transactions in a different way.

Comment: Thank you, Yuri. Can you make a suggestion for how the above code should be changed to avoid this?

Comment: Check ['SessionInView'](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView) approach (sessions/transactions are managed in a servlet filter). Really easy to adapt that example.
Also in [JBoss Seam](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Seam_Reference_Guide/persistence.seam-managed-transactions.html) they do this stuff in a JSF phase listener, so it's more finer-grained and JSF-ish

Comment: PS: if you could migrate from Tomcat to [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html), which should be straightforward, and use EJB Lite it would take away all this boilerplate stuff